# How to connect to device's sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to find out how to connect to my phone's sqlite DB. I've had a look around on the net but cannot find anything i understand 100%.

So far i'm opening cmd prompt and changing to the android-sdk/platform-tools directory.
From here i'm running adb shell. From this point how do i connect to the phone's db?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This may give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal sqlite database for a phone. Each application may or may not have one or more databases of its own.

If you know the package prefix of a particular application, you might be able to get a copy of its database.

see:
[Location of sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/android-location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device?rq=1)