# What is the default database location of an android app for an unrooted device?? Is it same as for rooted one?

Tags: android, installation, rooted-device, installation-path

I have quite a specific question.

First let me explain what I am trying to do and then the problem.

Basically what I am trying to do is to store an existing .db database file in **assets** folder and then after installation I want to copy the .db file from assets to the default database location in Android. Something similar to this page answer [link][How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application).

**Problem** For unrooted device I cannot access `/data/data/<<package name folder>>` . In this case where is the database file gets stored. In other term I want to copy a file from assets to applications default location for database which is `DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"` in case of a rooted device. Would it be the same for the unrooted device.

Comment: yes but u wont able to read anything unless you r rooted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, For both the cases it will be same path. `/data/data/<application_package_name>/databases`

Now, on un-rooted device you can not access `/data/` directory of device's internal storage. That's why you can not seen the database file.

If you want to get the file you can copy database file from internal storage  `/data/data/<application_package_name>/databases` to external storage (sdcard) then using **ddms** or `adb pull` get the database file.

Also just try command `adb pull /data/data/<application_package_name>/databases/<database_file_name>` from your system to get the database file.

But by default all the android application store database on internal storage path `/data/data/<application_package_name>/databases`. And its applicable for all devices **rooted** or **un-rooted**.

Comment: I agree I cannot see the directory in an unrooted device but can I perform operation assuming the directory `/data/data/<application_package_name>/databases` exists. I want to copy a file from **assets** folder to the databases folder. Can I copy assuming the same directory path for rooted as well as unrooted device.

Comment: Yes, you can not seen the file, but you can access the database file within your application and perform any operation on it. As file already physically present there.

Comment: is there any app that can fetch db file from this location?

Comment: This answer is not correct anymore. For years I have been using this   directory for copying databases in and out of the app, today for some reason databases were stored in /data/user/0/<application_package_name>/databases This directory can be retrieved by context.getDatabasePath(String name) as posted below by cja.

Comment: Worth noting that within Android Studio, the "Device File Explorer" can be used to retrieve the database from the device; however, it is still located within /data/data/<application_package_name>/databases.

Answer (score 8):

According to Android docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String) you should use context.getDatabasePath.

Works for me:

```
File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(name_of_database_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default Android Stores its SQLite Database to this below link, where you can access your **.db** file by using **shell** from **command prompt** to get owner access using chmod for read or write permission.

```
String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;

Where:
String DATABASE_NAME = "your_dbname";
String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.your_app_name";
```

For more details you can check the following link. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42359626/4529588)