# Android Studio (Database From Asset Folder)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I followed this tutorial. [Link-](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html)
I successfully implemented what's in the tutorial.
After that I Use Update command to update my DB from the asset folder.
In my device i can see The updated part,
But when i Import the DB File to SQL DB Browser, the DB File remains unchanged. 
I need the DB File for other use so im using Android to fill the datas what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ship your Android app with a populated DB, then you should definitely use the [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) by [Jeff Gilfelt](https://github.com/jgilfelt). You can find a real example of how to use the library here: http://www.6020peaks.com/2015/03/how-to-ship-an-android-app-with-preloaded-data/

Update: I just saw that the tutorial you followed is also using sqlite-asset-helper. If I understood your question correctly, I think you are looking at the wrong db file. The file that you need and that will contain all the new data generated by your android app will be here: /data/data/application_package_name/databases.

Check this out for more info on that direction: [What is the default database location of an android app for an unrooted device?? Is it same as for rooted one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326455/what-is-the-default-database-location-of-an-android-app-for-an-unrooted-device)