# Connect to SQLite in android NDK NATIVE

Tags: android, c, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm connecting SQLite in **NATIVE** on android.

I'm Got this exception: `unable to open database file`

**my NDK code:**

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "DatabaseHelper.h"
#include "../sqlite/sqlite3.h"

const char* SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO FOO 
VALUES(1,2,3); INSERT INTO FOO SELECT * FROM FOO;";
const int ERROR_STATE = -1;
const int SUCCESSFULLY_STATE = 0;

int createDatabase() {
char TAG[20] = "NATIVE_SQL";
sqlite3 *db = 0; // хэндл объекта соединение к БД
char *err = 0;

// открываем соединение и тут вылетает ошибка! 
if(sqlite3_open("myDb.db", &db)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "Error opened database. 
%s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return ERROR_STATE;
}
...someone code
```

P.S.
if  `if(sqlite3_open("", &db)) {..` database created temporary file and remove it durning close. **If open("",&db) is work!**

How will I create the db connection with "myDb.db" name?

---

Or

```
if(sqlite3_open_v2("myDb.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "Error opened database2. %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return ERROR_STATE;
}
```

**Permissions in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You will need to pass a full path to a writable location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android app does not have its own 'home' directory. The underlying Linux-like runtime has getcwd(), and it will return `/` - i.e. the root of the filesystem. Note that the app does not own `/` and it cannot write to this directory.

This means that you must pass the full path to any file you want to open, including `myDb.db`. You probably want to keep the database in the [default database location for the app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326498/192373), such as returned by [Context.getDatabasePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)). The best easiest reliable way to get it in C++, is to have Java query it before calling native, and pass the path to C++.

Comment: Me helped: final `File file = context.getFileStreamPath("myDb.db");`