# Manage SQLite from Android Native C++ Code

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to know if it's possible to query a SQLite database from Android C++ Native Code using the NDK and JNI. If so, how would I go about doing it? Would have to create a Java or Kotlin class to manage that? Because I already have some c++ logic that manages an SQLite database, and I would like to integrate that code to an android project without having to start from scratch.

Comment: Where do you plan on storing this SQLite database? The answer determines how easy it will be.

Comment: I was under the impression that android devices already had a built in SQLite database, so I was hoping to store the tables there.

Comment: There are tens if not hundreds of SQLite databases on any given Android phone, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can attach to the database associated with your app like this answer: [Connect to SQLite in android NDK NATIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905877/connect-to-sqlite-in-android-ndk-native)