# Using external Android Sqlite-Database in a "Flex Mobile Project" of Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, sqlite, apache-flex, air

I have developed an Android-App "A" which uses a sqlite-database and an App "B" which has read- and write-access to the database of App "A". (In this case i'm using "Content Provider" for App A and "Content Resolver" for App B.)

But now I have to give a database-access from App A to an App C which is a "Flex Mobile Project" developed for Android-devices that use Adobe Air.

I have read on the adobe.com-homepage (https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/airquestions/Data) the following message:

"Adobe AIR provides a built-in database store based on SQLite."
(But, important for me:) 
"Adobe AIR does not provide APIs to connect directly to other databases, although it is possible to handle those connections using the ActionScript Socket API."

Does anyone of you have a solution for my problem? Maybe also an executable "Flex Mobile Project" for android as an example?

Thank you in advance.
Kind regards.
Alex

Comment: Where is your SQLite database file?
It's possible to access SQLite file, if you create SQLite database file at /mnt/sdcard/hoge folder.

Comment: As I know, the file of the database is here "/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>". That's what i have read in here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/android-location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device). But when I try to see/read it in the "File Explorer" of Eclipse (Android Edition) I don't have the permission to access the folder "/data".
How can I change the storage-path of my database. I'm using a "Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1"-Tablet with 16GB space and Android Version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2ways for share SQLite database between AIR app and native android app.

a)Create SQLite file at sdcard path. (/mnt/sdcard)
Any apps can access that SQLite file...

b)Create [ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) that includes Content Provider.
It's best way, but I'm not sure if it would be well.

Comment: Thank you Yasuyuki,
what does ANE mean? "ANE = Air Native Extension"?
I have no experience with flex or actionscript programming. So I think will try first the way a) with the sdcard path.