# How to add and open sqllite file in Android application?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, file-io

I've got file named `plik` in `assets` folder. My sqlhelper has a method called `databaseExist()`:

```
public boolean databaseExist()
{   
    System.out.println(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

My package name is:

```
package pl.mobiledietplanner;
```

Path and name is set as:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/pl.mobiledietplanner/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "plik";
```

In the activity I invoke this method:

```
MyDBHelper helper = new MyDBHelper(this);       
System.out.println(helper.databaseExist());
```

The result is:

```
/data/data/pl.mobiledietplanner/databases/plik
false
```

I've done everything as described on the [blog](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).
Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?

EDIT:

I also opened `File Explorer` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460901/2194222) and added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`. But the `data` folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

the files in asserts folder is not in your DB_PATH, you can do like this:

`AssetManager am = null;

·am = getAssets();

·InputStream is = am.open("filename");`

then judge whether the inputstream is null

note: my english is not so good,please don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you follow the checkDatabase() on the blog that you are referring to?

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){

  SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

  try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

  }catch(SQLiteException e){
    //database does't exist yet.
  }

  if(checkDB != null){
    checkDB.close();
  }

  return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I did:
`sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/data/data/pl.mobiledietplanner/databases/plik, db=/data/data/pl.mobiledietplanner/databases/plik`
`sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/pl.mobiledietplanner/databases/plik", &handle, 1, NULL) failed`