# path DATA/data/APP_NAME/databases/FILENAME. not exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an application that uses SqliteDatabase. So my application create tables and fill up its.
Now I want to find database file. (database.db).
I searched the whole forum and I found info that database is by default saved in the directory DATA/data/APP_NAME/databases/FILENAME.

But when I explore on my phone Data directory I can't find  my application directory.
Why ????? Where can I find my application directory ?? Where can I find my application database file ??

Actually, on my phone,in Data directory, there are directory such as:

```
com.adobe.reader
com.googgle.android.tts
com.google.android.youtube
```

.
....etc

but there is not

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: location of sqlite database on the device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/android-location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device)

Answer (score 0):

`APP_NAME` corresponds to the name of your application. So `com.adobe.reader`, `com.googgle.android.tts`, and `com.google.android.youtube` are all directories corresponding to applications.

You need to go into the directory corresponding to the application that you made (e.g. `com.mycompany.myappname`), and then the databases directory under that. Your database file and possibly its [journal file](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#rollbackjrnl) will be there.

Comment: I know that. But my application have package com.las.Wycieczka, but I can not find directory com.las.Wycieczka. Of course. my application is installed.

Comment: How did you install your application? Via an IDE, or via the command-line? Did you install your application to the SD card by chance? Try running `adb shell  pm get-install-location` to check.