# how to save static database android app on separate folder

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database android app for my college that stores students records and all the record are store in sqlitedatabse and the file name is STUDENT.sqlite.But that file is hidden and can be seen only if phone is rooted.so i need a solution so that the aap gets install it should show separate folder for it and the sqlite file mustbe there in it.so that when i put all records in that and save i can give that file so another person and he can view the same record.no need of entering all records again he can just change the sqlite file.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/android-location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy all records from your database into a public or shared directory on sd-card?

Comment: But if i want to replace the db file with another db for my app than its possible or not

Comment: Yes, its possible if the db-file is in a public directory. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the database file to yourdatabase.db and put it in your projects assets folder and on first run of application just copy that database to data directory of android system.