# Showing app and sqlite in android/data folder

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an app with an associated SQlite database which I have installed to my phone. It works fine.

I would like the app to create a com.mypackage.app folder in the Android/data folder.

My phone isnt rooted, but I can see other applications in this folder such as com.dropbox.android and com.google.earth. I can even see the associated sqlite databases for some apps I have installed.

Can anyone tell me why I cant see my own app and database in this folder?

Comment: By Default the data base is created in the internal directory which cannot be accessed without root permission. However, you can ask your app to copy the app to a location, where you can access the same.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a tutorial on doing this please?

Comment: Try this solution, this should work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154281/2758499. What he is doing is actually copying the db from internal directory to a directory which is accessible. So when you update the actual db, you will have to copy again to view the updated db in the accessible directory

Comment: I can see that the Android/data folder is actually on the SDcard. I used this tutorial to create the folder:http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/03/how-to-create-application-folder-in-sd.html and then dumped my database in there. Thank you

Comment: Ok then, post a solution and mark that as answer. So that other people can refer that

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the Android/data folder is actually on the SDcard.

I used this tutorial to create the folder:androprogrammer.com/2014/03/…

I have an option to backup my database using the details above provided by Saran to copy the database into the created folder