# Where is the default location of the sqlite database file created in phone storage

Tags: android, xamarin

There is a DBfile created as follows for xamarin code for native android for android sqlite database:

```
    public static string DBFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"Test.db");

 public static void InitializeLocalDB()
        {

            if (!File.Exists(DBFile))
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DBFile))
                {
                    connection.CreateTable<Model.TestItem>();
                }
            }
```

The model has also been coded.

Model

```
namespace Test.Model
{
    public class Test
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Test { get; set; }


    }
}
```

May i know where is the default location for the database file created from the above code in android phone as i tried using the file manager but cannot find the file?

Comment: just log the `DBFile` to the console, and you will see the path

Answer (score 1):

The file "test.db" would be within your app's sandbox and thus normally not accessible (unless you are using a rooted device or a non-production image for the emulator )

On Android this:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

Maps to (adjust to your package name of course):

```
/data/user/0/com.sushihangover.someApp/files/Test.db
```

Comment: I have deployed the app into my android device but I do not see the package in Android data folder,how do I create the package in xamarin to access the dB file

Answer (score 0):

```
/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

as they say in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device).

In physical devices, not emulators, the problem is that, sometimes, depending on the phone, you cannot access that folder.
For example i have a normal Android tablet, not rooted. If the app is in Debug (not release), i am able to access that folder from Android Studio Device Explorer.

Sometimes it cannot be accessed that way, for example in certain Samsung phones (it says `run-as package is unknown`), so i use adb and the method described in [this other post](https://www.liammoat.com/blog/2017/pull-an-sqlite-database-file-from-an-android-device-for-debugging).

**Edit**: Sorry i didnt realize you were asking about Xamarin. Anyway i'll leave you the images from my Android Studio Device File Explorer, just in case it can help you.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I look at other apps,the packages folder are in /data folder instead of /data/data/package_name

How is it done?
So my current apps package folder is in in accessible /data/data folder,is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ThomasKoh The data (not the app itself) from every app, is inside /data/data/ and inside you can see cache, database, shared_prefs, etc.I just tried in my tablet and took that screenshot. I tried the same in my Samsung and i couldn't see the same, cause for any reason, Samsung doesnt allow it.

Comment: I have tried installed android terminal emulator to access the folder,anyone know what is the full path to the /data/data folder?

Comment: I have asked another question on how to change the location of the db which maybe another way to get around.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887586/how-to-specify-a-specific-location-for-db-file-where-i-can-access-instead-of-sta

Comment: You can code a simple method in your app that copies the .db file to an accesible folder of your choice, and from there access it.