# How to specify a specific location for db file where i can access instead of standard application /data/data/appid/database

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to create a sqlite db at a specific location in android where i can access it easily using a file explorer.
I do not want the sqlite db created to be in the default /data/data/appid/database folder which is protected by root and unable to access it through any file manager or rooting the android which is dangerous.

How do i specicify specific android file location like /storage/emulated/0/db using xamarin?

The current file location set is as follows which will go to the inaccessible default application folder:

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Db.InitializeLocalDB();
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.action_settings)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            View view = (View) sender;
            Snackbar.Make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LengthLong)
                .SetAction("Action", (Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener)null).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Db.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
//using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Android.App;
using SQLite;

    namespace App1
    {
        public static class Db
        {
    //public static string DBFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.db"); //Call Database
    public static string DBFile = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "test.db"); //for tmp use

            public static void InitializeLocalDB()
            {

                if (!File.Exists(CommonVar.DBFile))
                {
                    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Db.DBFile))
                    {




                        connection.DropTable<Model.ItemMaster>();
                        connection.CreateTable<Model.ItemMaster>();

                    }
                }

                }
}
}
```

ItemMaster.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SQLite;

namespace App1.Model
{
    public class ItemMaster
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Catalog { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Qty { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string UoM { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LotNumber { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Mtype { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Length { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string MGrp { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string ExpiryDateRaw { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string ExpiryRange { get; set; }
    }
}
```

if i use the default app folder using this path,it is fine:
public static string DBFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.db"); //Call Database

If i set the download folder,i got error cannot open the database.

[image]

I have already set write and read access to manifest file and set write to external memory as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea?

add the correct path /storage/emulated/0/db/Test.d,still same error.

[image]

Have also tried check access to the folder by putting a txt file and opens it with no issue.

[image]

Use a terminal to check db folder permissions as follows:

[image]

Any clues?

Also tried copy datafile to external db folder,failed with the following:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use PCL storage to save in external memory?? Then I can help you.

Comment: Nope, i can check it out first,i am beginner to android and xamarin development

Comment: Well you cannot place your DB file in the downloads folder since it is inaccessible to your SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a copy function to copy/move your private/sandboxed SQLite file to a public directory of the device, something like:

```
public void CopyDBToSdCard(string dbName)
{     File.Copy(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbName),
        Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, dbName));
}
```

Note: This is using native Android API to obtain the Downloads dir, so you could do this via a Forms dependency service.

Note: Your app would need external storage permissions (manifest **and** runtime-based)

You could just directly use a public storage area on the device, such as Downloads, Documents, etc. Your app would need manifest/runtime permission to access those locations.

```
var DBFile = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads,"Test.db");
```

You could just hard-code the public directory path for debugging (do not hardcode the path in a production app as different devices could have different paths, use the Android APIs to dynamically obtain the correct one for the device that it is running on).

- Use `adb shell` to obtain the correct path, ie:

  adb shell ls /sdcard

Example:

var DBFile = Path.Combine("/sdcard/Download","Test.db");

Note: Again your app needs manifest/runtime permissions for read/write access to these locations

Comment: I have edited my question trying out your solution but encounter cannot read dbfile,not sure why,i have already enable read access to external memory,any other setting i need to do?

Comment: @ThomasKoh I would assume that the exception on creating SQLiteConnection is due to the fact that are not requesting runtime access to external media. Reread my answer, it states that 3 times..

Comment: You would still need read access to the file, also assuming `Path.Combine("storage/e...` is a typo as the initial `/` is missing.

Comment: what do you mean by runtime permissions,where do i set it?

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/  & https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: But i have already permitted runtime permissions for write and read access to external storage as the snapshots in manifest

Comment: @ThomasKoh Manifest permissions entries are not "Runtime Permissions", Marshmallow (and above) changed all that, you have to provide both. (Same hold true for iOS, there are plist.info permissions and also runtime permissions, they are implemented differently as, well, they are different OSs, but the end-result is the same, you have to ask the user for permission).

Comment: Also tried the copy method,also failed ,i think no access to the default app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Using SushiHangover's method,there is an addition step that needs to be done so that the app can access the storage as below:

After deploying your app into android device:

Settings->[your App]

[image]