# How do I manually add extra textview without adding it in axml

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

i am trying to extract one data at a time from the sqlite database from the application and for every data return from the sqlite table,i will need to output the data into the GUI with every textview created for every return result else will throw message not found. i am using xamarin native android.

How do i achieve that,i am new to xamarin?

e.g i have a textedit for user to input values database table values(1,2,3,4) if user puts 1,there will be a textview below the textedit with value 1 created And if user continue to put 2,another textview below (the textview with value 1) will be created with value 2

E.G Below:
1)Edittext for user input

[image]

2)When user input values 1 in the editbox,it matches the values in the database and return the value 1 as below:

[image]

3)When user input another value 2 in the editbox,it matches the values in the database and return value 2 as below:

[image]

Cuurently,my code is as follows:

DB.cs(to create the sqlite database in a folder in android that i can access instead of the default application folder)

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public static class Db
    {
  public static string DBFile = testPath.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "test.db"); //for tmp use

    public static List<Model.Test> TestList = new List<Model.Test>();

     public static void InitializeLocalDB()
            {

                if (!File.Exists(Db.DBFile))
                {
                    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Db.DBFile))
                    {
                        connection.DropTable<Model.Test>();
                        connection.CreateTable<Model.Test>();

                    }
                }

                }
}
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace TestApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Db.InitializeLocalDB();

        }
```

Once i am able to create the database in the download folder,i will extract the db file and manually add in data with compactview to test the app.

Comment: What have you done so far have you tried anything,Also show a visual representation of what you want

Comment: I have edited my question with the visualization,currently now i also have issue creating the sqlite database in defined specific folder like public folder Downloads which i have asked on another thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887586/how-to-specify-a-specific-location-for-db-file-where-i-can-access-instead-of-sta

Comment: Well from my understanding you will have to write the code for this which is sort of complex so i would suggest you upload your axml file and i can write you the code to add it then.