# Android Room: Save and export database in SQLite format

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I use Room to save my data :

```
@Database(entities = {Colis.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class ChloeDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ColisDao colisDao();
    private static volatile ChloeDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static ChloeDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (ChloeDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            ChloeDatabase.class, "my_database")
                            // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                            // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

But what I really want is to save data in `sdcard` in sqlite format (so that I can export `my_database.sqlite` file in `/sdcard/Android/data/my_package/my_database.sqlite`, whether it's on a emulator or a real device).

I searched for a whole day on Internet without finding the solution.
Could anyone help me with this issure ?

Answer (score -1):

You can extract your database, after you have connected your emulator or physical device like this:

- Go to DeviceFileExplorer
- data
- data
- find you app name
- databases

  and than find your database. It is the file with the larger size . Than drop it to your phone storage. After that if you want to check your data in your computer, you can perform queries in Sqlite syntax with [this](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) little toy here .

Comment: Hi, I think you missed the point, I want to save my database programatically in sdcard directory

Comment: but the sqlite is a file with the sufix .sq , I am a little confused

Comment: my bad, but I found nothing with suffix .sq

Comment: or maybe it is a .sqlite ,not sure about it , but the thing is  : When you create a database it is a file itself with the database suffix on it's own

Comment: so the answer is if you want to move this file somewhere else you  have to do it this way , otherwise it is already created in your storage

Comment: you can find this link here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device