# Creating a byte array from an SqliteDatabase to save it with Google Saved Games?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, google-play-games

I have a game where I use a couple of tables to store player's progress. It is quite long game so from time to time I'm having this legitimate user feedback about why I don't have cloud save option?

Therefore I **do use Google Play Games sign** in to have achievements, I thought I could simply implement [Google Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) as well, straightforward.

As I see, it uses a simple `byte[]` array to save & load game progression **from the cloud.** (Google Drive, actually.)

My question is, how can I create a `byte[]` array **which holds the FULL database of a player's saved game instance?**

I'm using **Sqlite Database** like:

```
private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;


private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "duels_rpg_db", null, 123);
  

    this.ctx = context;

 
    getWritableDatabase();
}


public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {

   
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

and so on, nothing extraordinary.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good idea to serialize your user data instead of the db file instead. This way if you update your app, you wont app to worry about using a newer version of the DB in a not-yet-updated version of the app.

So I would recommand convert your progress to and from org.json.JSONObject.
With the JSON, it's easy to convert to an byteArray with `json.toString().getBytes("utf-8")`

On fetching the data, you can convert it back to json and wirrrte a method that load your sqlite db with the data of the json

Comment: Good idea but that would be only okay if the database would be small, and I would know that it would never will be bigger. But right now I have 20+ tables. Writing a serialization operation is out of the question, sadly. The safe and code less version would be to simply grab the whole database and override the old one. I will have to handle version checking with both methods anyway.

Comment: I can relate! :) Then this link my provide insight on how to customize the location of your db file and access / overwrite it. https://riptutorial.com/fr/android-sqlite/example/16326/sqliteopenhelper-avec-nom-de-chemin-d-acces---base-de-donnees-de-base-de-donnees-qualifie-complet-dans-le-dossier-public

Comment: It is not a real answer to the question but I ended up using this solution. Sqlite wrappers are a pain in the a**

Answer (score 2):

If you were [using C it would be easy to serialize the entire database](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/serialize.html), but in Android I think you would have to [locate the database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device#:%7E:text=Android%20stores%20the%20file%20in,%2C%20move%2C%20or%20delete%20it.), convert it to a byte array using the ByteArrayOutputStream class, store it in Google Saved Games and later on convert the byte array back to a file if necessary. For an example of converting a file to a byte array and vice-versa [see this link](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20a%20file%20to%20byte%20array%2C%20ByteArrayOutputStream%20class%20is,toByteArray()%20and%20toString().).